# Cascade delete from the same table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, cascade, cascading-deletes

Hi I am using JPA2 with Hibernate implementation and I got a simple mapping like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = ALL)
  private List<SubscribedUser> subscribedUsers;

}
```

and a second table (SubscribedUser) with id class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "subscribed_users")
@IdClass(SubscribedUserId.class)
public class SubscribedUser {
  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_user", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private User user;

  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_subscribed_user", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private User subscribedUser;
}
```

Lets assume we got 2 records is a subscribed_users table : 
1.

```
user | subscribed_user
1    | 2
```

2.

```
user | subscribed_user
2    | 1
```

The problem is that when I delete User with id = 1. the first record is deleted correctly with cascade option, but I got an error, because there are is a still reference to a User with id = 1 in the second entry in subscribed_users table. Is there a possibility to cascade delete also second record?

Thanks

Dawid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you can't do it automatically without bidirectional relationship between `SubscribedUser`'s, so add something like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "subscribedUser", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private Set<SubscribedUser> dependentUsers;
```